# Pause VM when SQL server idle

Tags: macos, sql-server, vmware-fusion

In OSX Mountain Lion, I run a Windows Server 2003 VM solely to run SQL Sever 2008. It chews up a lot of battery life. Is there some way to automatically pause the VM when the SQL Server is idle and restart it again when requested (kind of like wake-on-lan)?

**Update:** I can get it to pause when idle by setting the power setting in Windows to put the system to sleep. However, I cannot get it to start back up again.

Comment: Automatically? Or manually?

Comment: Automatically. Ideally it would start it when it was requested and pause it when idle for some number of minutes.  Question updated to be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, sql server cannot do anything once the OS is asleep.

That leaves hardware (or virtual hardware). If you could modify the clients to check how long it was since they last accessed the server and if it was longer than windows leep time send a wake up call, pause while windows boots again, and then continue; then yes, you could.

I bit more practical might be to just run an sql server on OSX.